# Why does smashing a TV remote load its batteries?

Tags: electricity, soft-question, electric-circuits, everyday-life, physical-chemistry

Many times I had the same problem: my TV remote's batteries were too weak for it to operate, but then, when I shook the remote a bit and smashed it on my palm, somehow the remote regained its ability.

I'm pretty sure that many people faced this phenomenon.

Why does this happen?

PS: Contacts are OK.

Comment: Do you mean a TV remote? (A TV pilot would be the introductory episode/film of a new series)

Comment: @AcuriousMind Yes. I meant a TV remote. I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: Funny, usually when I hit my remote or tech like that it stops working entirely. Maybe electronics just don't like me very much

Answer (score 3):

Batteries contain various liquids that are important for the voltage to be produced. Sometimes, the liquid – even water – may turn to gas and it is permanently lost, along with the capacity.

Sometimes, the liquid just moves to one side of the battery which is also bad. Shaking a weak battery may homogenize the concentration of the liquid across the battery. Shaking helps at least in the case of a "stratified battery" which indicates a much higher voltage than what it may actually provide.

Comment: The kind of batteries that go into TV remotes don't really have liquid inside.  At best its a paste in between layers of stiffer material.

Comment: Great Olin, I may agree, but isn't a paste nothing else than a viscous liquid? Moreover, alkaline (AA) batteries as well as NiMH and Lithium-ion batteries seem to contain classic liquids, don't they? At any rate, if nothing "moves" inside the battery - like in a liquid - then the battery cannot work!

Comment: Yes, but quite viscous in this case.  Stuff really doesn't move around much inside these kinds of batteries.  The paste is usually between layers of electrodes that are rolled up.  Think of a jelly roll.  Shaking a jelly role isn't going to make the jelly move around much.  All this is totally different in lead-acid batteries like in your car, but that's not what's inside typcal AA or AAA batteries that go into TV remotes.

Comment: Bulk material doesn't move around inside this kind of battery, but ions still migrate thru the electrolyte.

Comment: Ions are matter, Olin. Nuclei have to be able to migrate from one side to another, so it's clear that the room left by them will be filled by something else.

Comment: @LubošMotl - the way the battery is constructed, the septa separating the electrolytes can simply move a tiny bit if needed to accommodate the mass flow of ions. I am pretty sure there is no air space, and given the high viscosity and the aspect ratio of the compartments, there is no practically significant motion of the electrolyte. Removing a tiny bit of copper oxide from the contacts, on the other hand - that's very likely. Also - remotes almost always use AA or AAA batteries - no "voltaic stack".

Comment: If the lithium ions cause an insignificant or tiny redistribution of the locations of lithium vs the electrolyte, then the capacity of the battery (energy or charge per unit mass) is also insignificant and tiny! You can't really separate these things. In lithium-ion batteries, there are no electrons flowing through the electrolyte - it is an electron insulator - and it's only the ions that make the current and ions are heavy because they include the nuclei. You can't make this motion negligible for efficient batteries - it's how they work!

Answer (score 3):

I think the shaking action causes the batteries to move slightly, thus 'scraping' the contact area on the batteries and the contact elements in the remote.  This improves the conductivity, and so on. Certainly I've had success opening the battery compartment and physically rotating the batteries and/or scraping the contacts gently.

I think it's unlikely that typical AA batteries have enough fluid in their interior. See, for example, http://www.instructables.com/community/All-right-lets-clear-this-up-What-the-hell-is-i/ , which does state there's some fluid in the electrolyte, but so far as I know (which isn't much :-) ) it's quite viscous.

Take a look at http://www.instructables.com/community/All-right-lets-clear-this-up-What-the-hell-is-i/  or http://www.explainthatstuff.com/batteries.html  for other discussions of the types of electrolytes (often a powder, not a fluid).